# Express req.user is optional even behind an authenticated middleware

Tags: typescript, express, passport.js

When using Passport with Express, Typescript thinks req.user is possibly undefined inside a route when using an auth middleware. When using an auth middleware, I'd like req.user to be defined in all cases because otherwise, the middleware will return 401 unauthorized response.

If the route is using an auth middleware like this:

```
app.use( '/users', passport.authenticate('bearer', { session: false }), usersRouter );
```

The routes within /users shouldn't have the user being possibly undefined since it never will be.

How does one achieve this, without declaring a custom request interface to use for each route?

Comment: Could you give a [mre] - where are you expecting the middleware to change the type of the request object in the handler?

Comment: If the route is using an auth middleware like this:

app.use(
  '/users',
  passport.authenticate('bearer', { session: false }),
  usersRouter
);

The routes within /users shouldn't have the user being possibly undefined since it never will be.

Comment: And how is that supposed to change the type of the userRouter or the request? The router type isn't defined by where it's used.

Comment: That's what my question is about, I'm not sure how that's implemented but I'm curious if it is possible. Otherwise, do I have to do something like if (!req.user) return res.status(401).send() at the top of every single route?

Comment: It can't, that's my point. The library types [add to the request object](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/b6d06e446d5433c79d7462998418787fc61aef42/types/passport/index.d.ts#L24), but they can't know for a given handler whether or not it will be set. Given that you have additional information, you can express that through an explicit type for the request argument, one way to do that being shown below, or using a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions).

Comment: Got it, thanks. Do you know if it's possible to override only the user on the request to be not optional (since most of my routes are authed) by default so I could then use the built-in one for unauthenticated routes?

Comment: You can extend the Express namespace's Request interface in the same way that library does, making the user non-optional, but then it can't warn you on routes that *aren't* authenticated.

Answer (score 1):

In short, you cannot make Typescript understand whether your middleware set `req.user` or not as TS doesn't "understands" how middlewares work in Express. However, you can extend the request interface and use your custom implementation where you know the value is set (aka in the authenticated routes).

Defining the custom interface:

```
import { Request } from 'express';
import { YourUserDefinitionInterface } from './your-user-definition.interface.ts';

export interface AuthenticatedRequest extends Request {
  user: YourUserDefinitionInterface 
}
```

Using it in a route:

```
// The below route is behind the auth middleware
app.get('/some-path', (req: AuthenticatedRequest) => {
  // Your handling logic here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this for quite a while. In the end, the simplest solution was to create a new custom property on the `Request` type, `authenticatedUser`.

In a `global.d.ts` file:

```
declare namespace Express {
  export interface User {
    id: string;
    otherStuff: any;
  }
  interface Request {
    authenticatedUser: User;
  }
}
```

Then in the application code, I can just call:

```
const someHandler: Handler = async (req, res) => {
  const { authenticatedUser: user } = req;
  logUser(user.id); // no TS errors!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In plain `javascript` its fairly easy to set property on the fly in the eg `req.user={name:"Jane",email:"janeDoe@gmail.com"`. But on coming to `Typescript` it's not that direct. My workaround around this problem is by setting a `dynamic property` on the request object and having a custom `express.Request` type that I use around all the requests

```
import {Request,Response,NextFunction} from "express"

export type RequestType = {
    [prop: string]: any
} & Request

export const Authorize = async (
    req: RequestType,
    res: Response,
    next: NextFunction,
) => {
    try {
        const AuthHeaderToken = req.headers.authorization
        if (!AuthHeaderToken)
            throw new ErrorResponse('Auth header token not provided', 400)
        const token = AuthHeaderToken.split(' ')[1]
        return jwt.verify(token, SECRET_KEY!, (err, payload) => {
            if (err)
                throw new ErrorResponse('Invalid or expired auth token', 400)
            req.user = payload
            return next()
        })
    } catch (err) {
        return next(err)
    }
}
```

For this implementation you can set any property to the Request object on the fly. Hope it works for you